# Не работает слово в выборке MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. При выборке (через CRON проверка актуальности записи) столкнулся с непонятностью .

```
  $db_query = "select count(*) from ".DB_PREF."advert 
               where on_delete='off' ";
  $kol = obr_db_query_count($db_query);
```

Не хочет делать выборку на проверку слова `off` (как будто стоп-слово какое-то)
Сама колонка `enum (on, off)` - показ : да, нет

Если изменить `off` на любое другое слово, то проблем никаких . Подскажите, где копать, а то в данная колонка фигурирует во многих выборках и просто заменить ее будет накладно (также добавлю : в других скриптах, которые без крона, работает все нормально)

Comment: Выведите на просмотр `$db_query`, выполните полученный текст на консоли, убедитесь, что запрос НЕ выполняется (или что выполняется). Хотя если не из cron всё в порядке - тогда лучше поднимите генеральский лог... В зависимости от результата - дальнейшие действия. PS. Проверьте, не кириллическая ли "o" в литерале 'off'...

Answer (score -2):

Слово `'off'` действительно является стоп-словом. Вот здесь приведен список таких слов: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-stopwords.html

Comment: Оно является стоп-словом только при полнотекстовом поиске.